# how to get content from Solr to drupal?

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-modules, nutch

I have crawl some website with nutch and and index it with solr.Now i would like to pass these data to drupal and take use of there search interface.
Most of the tutorial only show indexing from drupal to solr but not from solr to drupal.

So how can i go about passing already indexed data from solr to drupal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to build a custom module to query your Solr index using the solr HTTP API, then present the results using Drupal theming and render API.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason why all tutorials say that is because that's the only possible direction. Solr is a search engine and it's not supposed to be a "source" system for feeding another storage (like a ln RDBMS): things are supposed to be exactly in the opposite way (e.g. Nutch --> Solr, RDBMS --> Solr)

Comment: So if it is a source i can i can connect my source to the interface.You can connect RDBMS to a website with already filled data.

Comment: Yes, in the best scenario there would be a Drupal plugin for doing that, but I'm not aware about that. In the opposite, you could create some custom page that connects to Solr, retrieves and shows that content